# What normally people use to automatic update ssl certs?

Tags: ssl

I see that [FabioLB](https://fabiolb.net/feature/certificate-stores/) support multiple certificate stores, but unlike [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https) it doesn't have automatic https (certs doesn't renew automatically). What usually people use to automatically update SSL certs? cron+certbot+consul command line to set in this case if certs stored in consul (not vault)? [letsconsul](https://github.com/hypersleep/letsconsul) also looks can be modified to support Fabio. [Nomad](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/transport-security/security-enable-tls) and [Consul](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/tutorials/security/tls-encryption-secure) can generate certs easily but not automatically renew.